# How to repair an i Robot tablet which won't boot?

Tags: boot

My I.Robot 7180 ICS OS4.0 tablet was drained, when charged I tried to open it again but it was only stucked loading in the black screen with android logo showing. How to make this work again?

Answer (score -1):

Consider doing a full wipe of your tablet. I had this on a Galaxy Tab. Follow those instructions but **remember you will lose all your data**.

*Instructions:*

1. Turn off your Android Tablet.
2. Press and hold Volume + and Power button.
3. Release Volume + and Power button when you see message on screen.
4. On Android Stomach Repair Logo Screen, press again Volume + and Power   button.
5. On Hard Reset Menu Screen, use the Volume button to scroll up and down and use the Power button to select (click on).
6. Scroll down to Wipe Data / Factory Reset and click on it.
7. Scroll down to Yes – Delete All User Data and click on it.
8. After Data Wipe Complete click on Reboot System Now.

Source: http://www.askmefast.com/_why_does_my_android_warp__phone__keep_freezing-qna6151757.html#q3381869

Comment: mfw both of my answer and OP got downvoted